# .text() method in jQuery not working for xml element for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have the following javascript:

```
function getMessageFromXML(xml) {
    alert('xml: ' + xml);
    alert("Text of message: " + $(xml).find('dataModelResponse').find('adminMessage').text());
    return $(xml).find('dataModelResponse').find('adminMessage').text();
}
```

which is being executed on the following XML:

```
<dataModelResponse>
  <adminMessage>BARF</adminMessage>
  <adminData>
    <identifier>123456</identifier>
  </adminData>
</dataModelResponse>
```

I know that the XML is correctly passed in, because of the first alert, but the message is showing up as blank for some reason. I verified that there were exactly 1 message and 1 dataModelResponse elements in the xml, using the .length modifier for similar find() queries, but for some reason, I can't get it to print out the correct message.

Suggestions?

EDIT: Changed the tag name I was searching for. Posted in between two revisions, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see a `message` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `$(xml).find('dataModelResponse').find('message').text();` with `$(xml).find('message').text();`.

The documentation for `jQuery.find()` states:

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector.

The root level element of your XML block is `dataModelResponse`.  By calling `$(xml).find('dataModelResponse')`, you are essentially asking for a `dataModelResponse` within your `dataModelResponse`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing.

Comment: @jwir3 Is this working in IE? I remember that there was some issue with using find() this way in IE.

Comment: Ritesh: I haven't checked in IE yet. I actually only use FF, and it's an administration tool for myself and 1 other person, so it might not be a big deal if it doesn't work. However, I will check in the event you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

After `$(xml)` you’re already on the root node, which is `dataModelResponse`. Thus you will not find any child-elements of type `dataModelResponse`, and thus `text()` will return nothing.

Concrete:

```
console.log("Text of message: " + $(xml).text());
```

Will log

```
Text of message: BARF 123456
```

And (*this is what you want*)

```
console.log("Text of message: " + $(xml).find('message').text());
```

will log

```
Text of message: BARF
```

And

```
console.log("Text of message: " + $(xml).find('dataModelResponse').text());
```

will log

```
Text of message:
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Should it be `'adminMessage'` instead?

Comment: Yep, I changed it. Sorry, posted in the midst of a revision.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery 1.5, you can write:

```
alert("Text of message: " + $($.parseXML(xml)).find('adminMessage').text());
```

or

```
alert("Text of message: " + $($.parseXML(xml)).find('dataModelResponse > adminMessage').text());
```

or

```
alert("Text of message: " + $($.parseXML(xml)).find('dataModelResponse').find('adminMessage').text());
```